# Button with hidden menu iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

I need to implement a single button which would be shown at upper right corner of the application on UIView or MKMapView. On clicking that button a combo should come up and user would be able to select the categories.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You want to achieve something like this ?
http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/camera-flash-toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an UIButton and add it as a subview of your UIView (for example in viewDidLoad method if your view is linked to an UIViewController).

```
UIButton *showButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
showButton.frame = CGRectMake(500, 20, 150, 44); // hardcoded frame, not quite elegant but works if you know the dimension of your superview
[showButton setTitle:@"Show Categories" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// add target and actions
[showButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
// add to a superview, your parent view
[superView addSubview:showButton];
```

Then you add a method, called buttonClicked: that takes an id parameter (usually the sender, showButton in this case).

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
 // visualize categories
}
```

To visualize the categories you can follow two different ways:

1. Present a UITableViewController inside a UIPopoverController (only for iPad device)
2. Show a modal controller presenting a UITableViewController (both iPad and iPhone devices).

The UITableViewController allows you to have a list of categories and then select one of them.

P.S. Check the code in XCode because I've written by hand (without XCode)

Comment: thanx flex, How about the idea of a cell view, in which a single row will be visible and clicking on that row will show the hidden rows to choose categories? will this work ..
i am trying to implement your suggestion

Comment: i have to made it for IPHONE only

Comment: I think it's not a simple solution...but you could implement it using a UINavigationController that is presented through one of the two options described above. The UINavigationController allows you to switch, for example, from a more general view to a detailed one, as your case.